# How can I escape quotes on a PHP system call?

Tags: php, perl

I'm passing to perl from php using [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php)

```
system("perl -e '" . escapeshellarg($inp) . "' >> /tmp/out");
```

And get unterminated quoted string from perl.

Input is: `'Single quoted terminated string\n';`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please note that [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) adds the outer single quotes itself.

So *you* should leave them out:

```
system("perl -e " . escapeshellarg($inp) . " >> /tmp/out");
#              ^                            ^ no extra ' quotes here
```